# Crystal Reports conditional Grouping

Tags: crystal-reports

Not sure how to approach grouping a report that can group things differently depending on condtions. Here's the scenario. I have companies, policy numbers and products. Sometimes a policy can cover more than one company, but sometimes a single company can have more than one policy.

So in the first case where a policy covers more than one company it would look like this:

```
Policy > Company > Product
```

In the other case where a company can have multiple policies it would look like this:

```
Company > Policy > Product
```

Any ideas of how to approach this?

Comment: Would there always be 3 levels of grouping?

Comment: Yes, a policy might cover more than one company, but if that is the case then a company would not also have multiple policies with in it so it is always either policy > company > product or company > policy > product. Basically how it works is that small companies are often grouped together and covered under one policy, whereas a large company might be split up to be covered by more than one policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a parameter to allow a person to choose one of the two paths
- Create 2 formula fields that use the parameter field to choose between the database fields:

```
// {@level_1}
Select {?grouping}
Case "Policy > Company > Product": {table.policy}
Case "Company > Policy > Product": {table.company}
Default: {table.policy} 

// {@level_2}
Select {?grouping}
Case "Policy > Company > Product": {table.company}
Case "Company > Policy > Product": {table.policy}
Default: {table.company}
```

- Create a group for each formula field and one for the product field

Comment: The report needs to have both types of grouping in a single report. Basically we have a vendor that specified that they want to see their reports broken down by policy number regardless of whether the policy covers multiple companies or if a single company contains multiple policies. This in itself is not necessarily a difficult task. Where I am running into issues is in trying to get running totals for some of the other things they want in the report. If I group by policy as the top level group top, I cant seem to get the right totals for cases for when when policy is at a lower level

Comment: I have a lot of flexibility in terms of how I approach this report. This is an automated report that is exported, so I have the option of taking some of the logic out of the report and putting it in a stored proc or conditionally feeding parameters to the report via C#.

Comment: I ended up simplifying the report to not need the company grouping so it is just Policy > Products and no longer matters if Company is at a higher group level that policy. I'm going to accept your answer since it is a good suggestion and may help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are two ways to show the data into categorised groups,
Say in example For the first case where a policy covers more than one company

Policy > Company > Product

You Can either get count(*) records obtained i.e. no. of companies more than one under several policies you can create a formula and based on which a group can be inserted into the design view.

Another Way is to split the details section and on the basis of requirement suppress the unwanted section via conditions(x2 button).

Similar approach is also possible by using sub-report but is a bit complex task
but works for both scenarios.